# Is implementing client-side validation through an API realistic when it comes to performance?

Tags: angularjs, validation, asp.net-web-api

So in an ideal world both client side validation and server side validation can be defined in one place, so the validation only has to be written once and can be reused where ever.

The idea i have to solve this is to do all the validation through an API using ASP.NET Core. When the form data on the client changes it will send an AJAX request with the updated data model, which the API validates and in turn returns any possible errors. The client then shows these errors to the user directly.
This way it still looks like the good old client-side validation, but it actually all happens on the server.

I can already imagine the server load is going to be increased since a lot more API calls will be send, however the question is: 
will this server load be manageable in for example a big enterprise application with huge forms and complex validation?

And are there any other big drawbacks of this solution which i have to watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about an API not any other type of application with a back-end.

In this world, yes the validation of the payloads is important and needs to happen on the API side. In a way, the validation is the easiest part and less resource consuming since this is the first thing you check and if it doesn't pass then the API returns a 400 BadRequest HTTP code and nothing else happens.

There are systems where the validation, especially business rules validation does not happen on the API side. You could have for example a financial platform and the API is simply the gateway inside that world. In this case, the API acts as a pass-through and doesn't do much itself.

This being said, everything is susceptible to too much traffic, but you should be able to either throw enough resources at it, or have it deployed in the cloud and let it scale based on demand. You can load test APIs as well, to see how well they do under pressure, you must have an idea of how many calls you can expect in a certain period of time.

I wouldn't worry too much about it, I'd say validate what you can client side, so you don't even hit the API if there is no need for it and leave the rest to the API